# Need Help With NSDecimalNumber

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdecimalnumber

I'm trying to take an NSDecimalNumber I have, and multiply it by 1.1.

I have this but it doesn't work:

```
NSDecimalNumber *multipy = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:1.1 exponent:0 isNegative:NO]; 
NSDecimalNumber *savings = [totalExpenses decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:multipy];
```

Update:

Here is the whole code, does anyone know why it doesn't work?

```
NSDecimalNumber *totalExpenses = [[event.housePayment decimalNumberByAdding:event.carPayment] decimalNumberByAdding:event.loanPayment];
NSDecimalNumber *multiply = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:11 exponent:-1 isNegative:NO];
NSDecimalNumber *savings = [totalExpenses decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:multiply];
```

Crashes at multiplication line, with error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5d91a60'`

Comment: what message do you get when it crashes?

Comment: What is `event.housePayment` -- are you sure it is a `NSDecimalNumber`? Also are there any other lines of code in between that you have not shown us?

Comment: Yes it is NSDecimalNumber, all lines work fine except the multiplication line.  NSLog of totalExpense gives me the right number, and multiply NSlogs to `1.1` with that code.

Comment: Hmm I think its because I had them in different blocks in a switch statement.  Seems to be working by have two versions of totalExpenses.

Comment: right .. when you post your code I think it is best to post the whole code not just a few selected lines, because obviously here the code you posted is right, its what you didn't post that's wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mantissa needs to be an integer, so adjust for this by multiplying by ten and then reducing your exponent by one.

i.e.

```
NSDecimalNumber *multipy = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:11 exponent:-1 isNegative:NO];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
NSDecimalNumber *multipy = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:11 exponent:-1 isNegative:YES];
```